# What are the best hosting services for Drupal?

Tags: web-hosting, drupal

When I upload a drupal website on the web, I usually have issues such as:

- imagecache module failing to create duplicates of my images
- FUpload (multiple image upload) creating issues and warnings
- post size limit when I upload videos (PHP memory and post limit)

I want to solve all these issues and find a good hosting service.

ps. This is optional for now, I would like to have a hosting service with servers in Netherlands. Is this affecting the performances ? I mean, is the website going faster, or the location doesn't matter as long as the service is good ?

thanks
Patrick

Comment: Any company that supports MySQL and PHP will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal's own website has a [list of drupal hosts](http://drupal.org/hosting). I would think they can't be too bad if Drupal lists them on their website.

Answer (score 1):

Just about any cPanel hosting service will work - many have a free trial period and you can shop around to get the best rate (which isn't guaranteed if you go with a plain Drupal host).

Answer (score 0):

The List of the Drupal Hosts is a very good example. It containes all the major hosting companies that offer support for Drupal. You can check some of those such as [eApps](http://www.eapps.com/search.php?query=cPanel) for example, which offers both cPanel and  Plesk control panels.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of "a good hosting service" depends on your needs. An international company with a business critical web app requires different hosting than your kids' soccer club.

I have a shared hosting plan at [Deziweb](http://www.deziweb.com). Drupal runs fine on it, their prices are good and so is their customer service.

Answer (score 0):

Try [apex-3](http://www.apex-3.com) hosting

Great service

Comment: your answer reads a lot like an advertisement. If it's not, then you might want to elaborate a lot more.